# Is it possible to apply archivelogs from standby DB to Production DB?

Tags: oracle, recovery, rman, standby

I've lost two hard disks yesterday .  One contains an Oracle Datafile and another contains part of archive logs generated in the past 2 days. (say,  arch_5.dbf and arch_6.dbf are lost, in the set of arch_1 to arch_10).

I have switched over to my standby site as part of business continuity plan.

Now, I have to recover the missed datafile. It requires the missed two archive log files for recovery.

Is is possible to apply the same set of archivelogs from standby to production, in order to recover the datafile ?

Kindly advise.

~SK~

Answer (score 1):

It might prove a bit easier to
[Use RMAN Incremental Backups to Refresh a Standby Database](https://web.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10gR2/backup.102/b14191/rcmdupdb008.htm)
you could use the archives that are transported to the standby site but they won't help with the recovery of the lost datafiles, unless their creation is logged in the archives.

Using the incremental backup option is easier.

Comment: Thank You for the quick answer. The disk failure happened several hours after my Last Incremental backup.  
RMAN Point-in-Time recovery of missed DB file requires those missed archivelogs. 

Do I have to live with the data upto my last incremental  or Is there a way to do PITR using standby archivelogs ?

Comment: The idea is that you now take fresh incremental backup (from scn) and use that to recover the standby. If it is small, you might as well just create a fresh clone as standby. It also helps to mention the versions.